# Looking to import filter criteria from an excel table

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-tables

I am looking to import the list of unique value (the one in the filter menu of a table) in a vba code. Is it something possible? I know the autofilter method, but i can't find a way to import that list.

I've tried to use the autofilter function, but it doesn't work so far.

My code right now copy the column, then use the RemoveDuplicate function of excel. The problem I have with the code below is that the execution is slow. I saw that the list I am trying to build is already in excel, in the picture here (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fr4BKx8Jecahq3MPkZk8pRtqMsXGA6fI). As I saw that the list already exist, I would like to import it instead of building it.

I am open with any idea to make the execution of the macro faster.

Thanks and have a nice day,
Philippe M.

```
Sub LoadTagList() 

Dim rangeToFilter As Range
Set rangeToFilter = Sheet1.Range("A1:AZ13470")
Dim criteriaToFilter As String

criteriaToFilter = Feuil4.Range("C2").Value & ""

'Supression des filtres
On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ShowAllData

'Application de filtre sur la liste Export DynAMo

Sheet1.Range("A1:AZ13470").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=criteriaToFilter

Dim tempArray As Long
Dim i As Long

'Feuil4: Form
'Feuil5: Listes

Feuil4.ComboBox2.Clear
Feuil4.Range("C3").Value = ""

Feuil4.ComboBox3.Clear
Feuil4.Range("G2").Value = ""

'Feuil5.Range("E:E").Value = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Value

Sheet1.Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=Feuil5.Range("E:E")

Feuil5.Range("E1").Delete 'on supprime le header

Feuil5.Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Feuil5.Range("E:E").Sort Key1:=Feuil5.Range("E1"), Order1:=xlAscending

lineTotal = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Feuil5.Range("E:E"))

For i = 1 To lineTotal
    Feuil4.ComboBox2.AddItem Feuil5.Range("E" & i).Value
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: It would be more easy for the people around to answer your query if you can add your piece of VBA code.

Comment: The code is now in the original message. Thanks for the advice.